# Does HTTPS verify the domain in the requested URL matches the SSL certificate Common name?

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure

I've noticed companies like cloudflare or wordpress.com seem to offer a kind of "3rd party" SSL certificate to their customers, and when viewing certificates of the websites that use these services, the `Common name`  often corresponds to cloudflare, sucuri, automattic etc and not to the domain name of the url being requested. here is a screen shot example

[image]

This seems to indicate that the browser (in this case chrome `Version 59.0`) doesn't check this. Does the TLS protocol require that the domain/hostname being requested has to match the Common name on the public key certificate?

Comment: To be exact, TLS doesn't require verifying hostname (it can be used for protocols that don't _have_ hostnames) but HTTPS does, see rfc2818.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does check the DNS name matches the certificate, however it also validates if the domain name is in the alternative name field.

If you download the [SSL certificate for `www.seedprod.com`](https://serverfault.com/questions/129503/save-remote-ssl-certificate-via-linux-command-line), you'll find:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

If you put that in a file seedprod.crt, you can then use openssl to view the full data in the certificate with `openssl x509 -in seedprod.crt -text`.

Then you will see:

> `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:`
>
> `DNS:ssl378094.cloudflaressl.com, DNS:*.braveeaglewealthmanagement.com, DNS:*.comingsoonpage.com, DNS:*.comologia.com, DNS:*.dinofurs.com, DNS:*.epikchat.com, DNS:*.heatpressnation.com, DNS:*.ivanti.com.au, DNS:*.ivanti.cz, DNS:*.ivanti.de, DNS:*.ivanti.es, DNS:*.ivanti.fr, DNS:*.ivanti.it, DNS:*.ivanti.pl, DNS:*.mtapay2.com, DNS:*.paulhowelldesign.com, DNS:*.scproperties.com.au, DNS:*.seedprod.com, DNS:*.theartofadvice.com, DNS:braveeaglewealthmanagement.com, DNS:comingsoonpage.com, DNS:comologia.com, DNS:dinofurs.com, DNS:epikchat.com, DNS:heatpressnation.com, DNS:ivanti.com.au, DNS:ivanti.cz, DNS:ivanti.de, DNS:ivanti.es, DNS:ivanti.fr, DNS:ivanti.it, DNS:ivanti.pl, DNS:mtapay2.com, DNS:paulhowelldesign.com, DNS:scproperties.com.au, DNS:seedprod.com, DNS:theartofadvice.com`

Note `DNS:*.seedprod.com` and `DNS:seedprod.com` are in there, so the certificate validates for `seedprod.com`.

Comment: thanks, that explains the mismatch for `seedprod.com`. Here is another domain that has the same mismatch issue but no X509 alternative name. https://nowayshecodes.com in which the domain name `nowayshecodes.com` doesn't appear anywhere in the cert. i.e the value for the Alternative names is: `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
DNS:*.wordpress.com, DNS:wordpress.com` any idea what is happening in that case?

Comment: @the_velour_fog: I don't know how you checked but the name `nowayshecodes.com` is contained in the certificate for `nowayshecodes.com`, right after `DNS:nowaypal.com` and before `DNS:nowaystosayit.com`. My guess is that you've checked with `openssl s_client` but forgot the `-servername ..` argument which is essential when SNI extension is needed as in this case.

Comment: *"It does check the DNS name matches the certificate, however it also validates.."* - not fully true. CN is long considered obsolete. That's why the standard requires that it should not be checked if DNS SAN exist. And since a few weeks at least Chrome abandoned CN checking completely and requires SAN. See also https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/security-changes-in-chrome-58/ about the details of *Common Name Support Removed*.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I checked by getting the PEM encoded cert with `echo -n | openssl s_client -connect nowayshecodes.com:443` then taking the base64 encoded text between `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----` and `---------END CERTIFICATE-----` then running that through `openssl x509 -text` . I just repeated and I'm still not seeing the domain name

Comment: @the_velour_fog: to cite myself: **but forgot the -servername .. argument which is essential when SNI extension is needed as in this case**

Comment: @SteffenUllrich ah you were right, thanks. here is the one liner I used in the end `openssl s_client -servername nowayshecodes.com -connect nowayshecodes.com:443 </dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' | openssl x509 -text`

Comment: @the_velour_fog: FYI `openssl x509` (and nearly all `openssl` commandline functions) will treat any other lines preceding a PEM block as a 'comment' and ignore them, so you don't need the sed, just `openssl s_client .... | openssl x509 -text [-noout]`